# pyinstaller binary not finding library files

Tags: python, linux, pyinstaller, software-distribution

I have a python program I'm converting to a single binary file and then moving to a different platform. When I run the binary it's complaining about a missing library. What's confusing is that it is present. How can I fix this error?

Binary Created:

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import pyaudio --hidden-import wave --hidden-import Logger  --hidden-import json --hidden-import websockets --hidden-import asyncio --onefile Run_SD.py
```

Running Binary (on different platform):

```
/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1
/usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1
~$ ./Run_SD
[3656] Error loading Python lib '/tmp/_MEIgqfADy/libpython3.7m.so.1.0': dlopen: libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But the library is on the platform:

```
/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1
/usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1
```

(on the source plaform it's at: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 )

Comment: Dug into this a bit more.. the missing file is libcrypt.so.1 which is not on the target system..

Comment: I tried not doing a onefile installer and just the normal pyinstaller and I see that libcrypt.so.1 is not added in the distribution directory - how can I have it added in correctly?

(If I manually copy libcrypt.so.1 into the directory on the target system everything runs nicely - so if I can also have it added to the single file I think it should work.... just don't know how to add it...)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution .. not sure it's the correct one, but it works.
I copied the missing file into the source directory and then added **--add-binary libcrypt.so.1:.** to the command line which includes the file into the build and then all works.